# Does IntelliJ start processes with Administrator rights?

Tags: windows-7, intellij-idea

I'm running IntelliJ on Windows 7 and I'm trying to solve a problem where I can't get Selenium to start. I think it might be related to privileges.

I'm starting IntelliJ with "Run as Administrator". Are the processes that are started by IntelliJ also then given Administrator rights?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, all the child processes should inherit the parent privileges.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely yes, in fact it is very difficult for an elevated process to start a process that is not elevated. You would have to use the Windows API, jump through a lot of hoops and it would work only in certain circumstances.